# How to disabled Group in AD

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have simple requirement to disable/deactivate group in AD. There are plenty of options for AD users & Computers but did not see anything related to groups.

Basically, We want to remove all member from the group and set group to InActive or disabled. I can think of below approach but not sure if it is right way to do it.

Remove-ADGroup is not option in our case due to some security and audit concerns.

1. Remove all members from the group and move group to non-operational OU
2. Remove all members for the group and set enable flag to "false"

Please suggest best way/solution to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at Get-adgroup,get-adgroupmember,remove-adgroupmember and Move-ADObject

Comment: You can change the group to a distribution group if you just want to disable any access it gives.  `Get-ADGroup testgroup | Set-ADGroup -GroupCategory Distribution`

Comment: Exactly you can convert the group  from security to distribution and all access will be revoked

Answer (score 0):

This command will remove an AD Group for you.

```
Remove-ADGroup
```

Comment: Thanks Bill but unfortunately Remove-ADGroup is not option for us due to security and audit concerns.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

**Get-ADGroup** will get all the groups,
**Get-ADGroupMember** will get all the member then **Move-ADObject** will move the group to another OU

```
$AdGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach($ADgroup in $ADgroups){ 

Get-ADGroupMember "$ADgroup" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "$ADgroup" $_ -Confirm:$false}

Move-ADObject -Identity $AGroup -TargetPath "OU=disable,DC=test,DC=local"

}
```